# sed unexpected character

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing the following script:

```
v="1,pop";
sed "$v/d" dir/file1
```

It gives me this error:

```
char 3: unexpected `,'
```

How to solve this?  Note: the value of `$v` cannot be controlled.

Comment: What are you expecting the `sed` command to do?  When the shell has finished expanding `$v/d`, you have an invalid `sed` command.  It might that you're wanting to delete lines that match what's in `$v`, in which case, to a first approximation, you should use `sed "/$v/d"`.  If you're looking for lines 1 to the first line containing `pop`, you've got to do work on the value in `$v` to generate `sed "1,/pop/d"`.  If you want to do something else, you need to describe what it is you _do_ want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `sed` in a wrong way.

```
$ v="1,pop";
$ cat file 
1,pop
Suku
JohnGeorge
stackoverflow
serverfault

$ sed '/'$v'/d' file
Suku
JohnGeorge
stackoverflow
serverfault

$ sed "/"$v"/d" file
Suku
JohnGeorge
stackoverflow
serverfault
```

If you want to substitute a bash variable inside `sed`, you need to surround it with quotes like I showed above. Also if you want to write modification to file, you need to use `sed` with `-i`.

Comment: The quoting above is wrong: `sed /$v/d file`, `sed '/'$v'/d' file`, and `sed "/"$v"/d" file` all do exactly the same thing, because none of the characters in quotes are shell metacharacters, and all quoting does is suppress the interpretation of metacharacters. Mind you, if `$v` contains (certain) metacharacters, you want *it* to be in double-quotes. Thus, `sed "/$v/d" file` is the recommended form.

Answer (score 0):

Using this way in script

v="1,pop"

sed "/^$v$/{

d

}" dir/file1

Answer (score -1):

You need the [hashbang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) so your shell knows how to execute the script.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Then you'll get...

> sed: 1: "1,pop/d": expected context address

...which tells your the commands were executed. :)